# What should next week's topic be?

Tags: discussion

Currently it's either Geocaching or Navigation (related?).  However, I'm open to ideas.  Reply below and vote please :)

Answer (score 2):

For some us, the camping season is finished this year. A good topic could be *how to properly store the summer equipment* (boat, camping, hiking etc...)